# Xcode 5 iOS 7 TableView with DetailViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, uitableview

When I choose some cell it doesn't show DetailViewController
That's cod from DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *imageName;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@end
```

Cod from DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize imageName,imageView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

And ViewController.m`
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "DetailViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController (){
    NSArray *soundtitles;
    NSArray *thumbs;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  //  self.title=@"Точки";
soundtitles = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"novaposhta",@"ac-2",@"vugovskogo",@"naykova ",@"iskra",nil];
    thumbs=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"thumbsnovaposhta.jpg",@"thumbsac-2.jpg",@"thumbvugovskogo.jpg",@"thumbnaykova.jpg",@"thumbsiskra.jpg", nil];
    tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.alpha=0.9;
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source
-(NSInteger) numberofSectionInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [soundtitles count];
}
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                           if(cell==nil){
                               cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                           if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
                            {
                                   cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


                            }

                                        }

  cell.textLabel.text=[soundtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[thumbs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;

}

   #pragma mark -
   #pragma mark Table view delegate
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableViewdidSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
  {
      NSString *selectedImage=[[NSString alloc]init];
      switch (indexPath.row) {
          case 0:
              selectedImage=@"novaposhta.jpg";
              break;
          case 1:
               selectedImage=@"ac-2.jpg";
              break;
          case 2:
               selectedImage=@"vugovskogo.jpg";
              break;
          case 3:
               selectedImage=@"naykova.jpg";
              break;
          case 4:
              selectedImage=@"iskra.jpg";
              break;
          default:
              break;
      }
      DetailViewController *detailScreen=[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
      detailScreen.imageName=selectedImage;
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailScreen animated:YES];

  }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Also i added NavigatorController, but it didn't help.

Comment: Welcome! If you want your question to be answerable, you'll have to add more detail. As it stands now, it's unclear what you're asking. You never described what you're expecting to happen, and what is happening instead.

Comment: why use alloc for nsstring

Comment: your question ok. after this what happen

Comment: Add nslog before pushViewController to check if the detailScreen is not nil.

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller? How? Where?

Answer (score 0):

if you copied code properly the reason in:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableViewdidSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

there must be space between `tableView` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: How can I save my values in DetailViewController? I just want to add value only once and when i will open my app after closing this value will be in this textfield. Thank's.

Comment: You should look at `NSUserDefaults`, `NSDictionary's writeToFile:atomically:` or even `CoreData`. But it an another question.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the method as below:

> -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
>       // your code }

Instead of your method

> -(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableViewdidSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath

you just forget to add space check both methods